# placement of object (refer to 10.4.11 of TC++PL 3rd edition)

Tags: c++

```
class X 
{
public:  
  X (int);  
  // ...
};
```

We can place objects anywhere by providing an allocator function with extra arguments and then supplying such extra arguments when using new:

```
void* operator new(size_t, void *p)       
{ 
    return p; 
} // explicit placement operator  

void* buf = reinterpret_cast<void*>(0xF00F); // significant address    
X*p2 = new(buf)X;  //construct an X at ‘buf;’ invokes: operator new(sizeof(X),buf)
```

What does it means? What is reinterpret_cast and what it is doing here?
explain broadly.....

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but I hope you're not going to start asking SO users to explain every single piece of "The C++ Programming Language, 3rd Edition".  It's a **big** book.  And it's a pretty good one too.  Read and re-read the chapter in question, I'm pretty sure you'll find your answers.

Comment: @Lou i am learning c++ from tc++pl. why do you ask such a ques??

Comment: @1000100 If you are just learning c++, you need not concern youself with allocator functions. Once you understand the basics and have written some programs, you can start to experiment in the fringes of the language. At that point, googling "operator new" and "reinterpret_cast" will yield results that you should be able to make some sense of. At that point, you should be able to ask a more specific question to help complet your understanding of these concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can call `operator new`. The first way I'm assuming you're familiar with:

```
X *p1 = new X;
```

With this usage you're telling the compiler to do two things:

1. allocate enough space to store an instance of X. This is done by calling the default allocator supplied by the standard runtime unless you globally overloaded `operator new` to do something different.
2. fill out X's data members and get it to a known initial state by calling one of X's constructors.

Now the second form of `operator new` presented in your code:

```
X*p2 = new(buf) X;
```

With this usage you're basically telling the compiler *do not* allocate space for X. Instead use the space provided by buf to construct this instance of X. Step 2 is still performed but step 1 is skipped.

The `reinterpret_cast<void *>` here is essentially telling the compiler whatever is at address 0xF00F, treat it as some generic data -- no type or size is associated with this data. This is equivalent to doing a raw C-style cast:

```
void* buf = (void*)0xF00F;
```

This is done to satisfy operator new's function signature:

```
void* operator new(size_t, void *p)
```

Note the generic pointer `void *p` -- that will take on buf's value passed in earlier. The cast is there to make their 'types' match. Also note that 0xF00F technically isn't a valid address but we'll pretend it is for this example.

And that is what the code above is doing, explained broadly.

Answer (score 1):

'reinterpret_cast' is converting a pointer to another pointer type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0w9f63b.aspx

```
void* buf = reinterpret_cast<void*>(0xF00o0F);
```

0xF0000F is converted to a 'void *' pointer.